# Data types conversion (unsigned long long to char)

Tags: c, parsing, tree, type-conversion

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with the following code?

```
__inline__
char* ut_byte_to_long (ulint nb) {

   char* a = malloc(sizeof(nb)); 
   int i = 0;
   for (i=0;i<sizeof(nb);i++) {
       a[i] = (nb>>(i*8)) & 0xFF;
   }
   return a; 
}
```

This string is then concatenated as part of a larger one using `strcat`. The string prints fine but for the integers which are represented as character symbols. I'm using `%s` and `fprintf` to check the result.

Thanks a lot.

**EDIT**

I took one of the comments below (I was adding the terminating `\0` separately, before calling `fprintf`, but after `strcat`. Modifying my initial function...

```
__inline__
char* ut_byte_to_long (ulint nb) {

   char* a = malloc(sizeof(nb) + 1); 
   int i = 0;
   for (i=0;i<sizeof(nb);i++) {
       a[i] = (nb>>(i*8)) & 0xFF;
   }
   a[nb] = '\0' ; 
   return a; 
}
```

This sample code still isn't printing out a number...

```
char* tmp;
tmp = ut_byte_to_long(start->id);

fprintf(stderr, "Value of node is %s \n ", tmp);
```

Comment: "string"? ??? Where's the terminating zero byte?

Comment: You're only breaking up the number `nb` into bytes (in little endian), so it's a binary format not compatible with strings/text. You're bound to have some zero bytes in there if you choose small numbers though.

Comment: For your question: Specify what kind of conversion you want. To display text (then this approach is wrong)? To little endian byte string (then this approach is close)?

Comment: Why is this tagged C++?  There is nothing C++ about this code...

Comment: @kaizer.se: I want to display this number as text. This code is part of a larger thing of representing a tree as a string.

Comment: an error in your code `a[nb] = '\0'` shoud be replaced by : `a[sizeof(nb)] = '\0'`.

Comment: but as user1071136 said, you will not have a string of ascii digits but a string of numbers between 0 and 255... why dont you use a function like : sprintf(target_string,"%lu",source_int) or the non standard : itoa(nb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you dont want to use `sprintf(target_string,"%lu",source_int)` or the non standard `itoa()`, here is a version of the function that transform a long to a string :

```
__inline__
char* ut_byte_to_long (ulint nb) {
    char* a = (char*) malloc(22*sizeof(char));  
    int i=21;
    int j;
    do
    {
        i--;
        a[i] = nb % 10 + '0';
        nb = nb/10; 
    }while (nb > 0);
    // the number is stored from a[i] to a[21]

    //shifting the string to a[0] : a[21-i]
    for(j = 0 ; j < 21 && i < 21 ; j++ , i++)
    {
        a[j] = a[i];
    }
    a[j] = '\0';
    return a;
}
```

I assumed that an unsigned long contain less than 21 digits. (biggest number is 18,446,744,073,709,551,615 which equals 2^64 − 1 : 20 digits)

Answer (score 4):

`strcat` is expecting a null byte terminating the string.

Change your `malloc` size to `sizeof(nb) + 1` and append `'\0'` to the end.

Comment: Thanks. I was doing that before doing the strcat. Modifying the intiial function to what you suggested, it still doesn't work. :(

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems.

The first is that the character array `a` contains numbers, such as `2`, instead of ASCII codes representing those numbers, such as `'2'` (=50 on ASCII, might be different in other systems). Try modifying your code to

```
a[i] = (nb>>(i*8)) & 0xFF + '0';
```

The second problem is that the result of the above computation can be anything between 0 and 255, or in other words, a number which requires more than one digit to print.

If you want to print hexadecimal numbers (0-9, A-F), two digits per such computation will be enough, and you can write something like

```
a[2*i + 0] = int2hex( (nb>>(i*8)) & 0x0F );   //right hexa digit
a[2*i + 1] = int2hex( (nb>>(i*8+4)) & 0x0F ); //left hexa digit
```

where

```
char int2hex(int n) {
  if (n <= 9 && n >= 0)
    return n + '0';
  else
    return (n-10) + 'A';
}
```